# How to assign a class to a variable with JavascriptCore

Tags: ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

I'm trying to use JavascriptCore framework for iOS but I'm facing a problem.

My simple javascript text :

```
NSString * jsCode = @"var log = require('log'); log.test();";
```

My Obj-c code :

```
JSContext * context = [[JSContext alloc] initWithVirtualMachine:[[JSVirtualMachine alloc] init]];

context[@"require"] = ^(NSString* sting) {
    NSLog(@"require ok");
    return [JsLogFacade class];
};

[context evaluateScript:jsCode];
```

All I want to do, is assign my JsLog class to the `log` variable in my javascript so I can evaluate `log.test()` after.

JsLogFacade.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <JavaScriptCore/JSExport.h>

@protocol LogJsExports<JSExport>
+ (void) test;
@end

@interface JsLogFacade : NSObject <LogJsExports>
@end
```

JsLogFacade.m

```
#import "JsLogFacade.h"

@implementation JsLogFacade
+ (void) test {
    NSLog(@"It's working");
}
@end
```

I've got no error but I don't see my NSLog. Note that if I remove my return statement inside my block, "require ok" works.

PS : I can't just do the code below because I'll have no idea what is the code inside my script at the end

```
context[@"log"]=[JsLogFacade class];
```

Do you have any idea why or even if what I'm trying to do is possible ?

Comment: Isn't the `JavascriptCore` only for MAC? I'm pretty sort that's what the documentation says and it's a private framework on iOS.

Comment: It's available since iOS 7. You can find many tutorials about it and it's working.

Comment: I hate to be the stick in the mud but have Apple said it's available for use or is it just being assumed because you can access it? All I can find is Apple documentation saying this is only available for Mac Developers and that yes the `UIWebView` and the new `WebView` use `JavascriptCore` but there is no documentation to say it can be used and will be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you not be assigning the context entry as an instance of your logger? As in:

```
context[@"log"]=[[JsLogFacade alloc] init];
```

or returning an instance rather than a class in your require code?

And should the function test not be an instance method as opposed to a class method?

```
@implementation JsLogFacade
- (void) test 
{
    NSLog(@"It's working");
}
@end
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake.. I just had to assign an instance ! Thanks :)
I also switched to an instance method. I'm not familiar with Javascriptcore and I was following this tutorial : http://hayageek.com/execute-javascript-in-ios/ ! Thanks again !